# Can't write into a .txt file in netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I have a file called `SAVE.txt`. It is in the same package as the class `k`. The problem is I can't write anything in the `.txt` file using the following code inside `k`:

```
File saveButton = new File ("SAVE.txt");
BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter (new FileWriter (saveButton));
output.write("something");
output.close();
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filepath",true));  
bw.write("Hello World!");  
bw.write("\n");  
bw.write("Hello World 2 !\n");  
bw.write("Hello World 3 !" + "\n");  
bw.close();
```

Try this?

Did you try something easy like this:

```
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("test.txt"); 
f.write("hello"); 
f.close();
```

Comment: what about this ---->fileWriter.write( " test " );
                     fileWriter.flush();
i forgot you have to flush

Comment: did it work?Yea i realized it was java dumb question on my part

Comment: if the last one didn't work try following this http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/write_to_textfile.html

Answer (score 0):

When you write `new File ("SAVE.txt")`, since you specified a relative path, it refers to a file `SAVE.txt` in the *current working directory*. **The current directory is in general completely separate from the directory corresponding to your Java package.**

When you run code in Netbeans, it should be possible to specify the working directory (look in the project settings). Set it to some well-defined location, like the root of your project. Now specify the path relative to that working directory. For example, you could use `new File ("out/SAVE.txt")`.